# How to add Intellisense for a language in Gvim?

Tags: vim

I'm a newbie to GVim and I use GVim on Ubuntu 10.4 OS. I'm learning Ruby now, and I want to add Intellisense for it. My question is: is it possible to add a set of API for GVIM, not only for Ruby but maybe for Perl, Java, C++...etc? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Intellisense is not available for (g)Vim 7+. It's a Microsoft-trademarked feature of Visual Studio.

Automatic, context-specific code completion for many languages *is* a feature of Vim, however. It's called Omni complete. Ruby, Perl, Java, and C++ all have plugins supporting omni completion.

Finding, installing, and optimizing plugins for all of the above languages is a fairly broad task, and likely beyond the scope of a single question. You should start with Vim's always excellent documentation at `:help compl-omni`. For Ruby omni completion you'll need Vim with Ruby support compiled in.

Furthermore, there are a lot of plugins for enhancing omni completion, which is usually triggered by typing `Ctrl-x Ctrl-O`. I personally like [AcpComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879), which allows omni completion suggestions to pop up automatically as you type without having to use the aforementioned key command. Many more language-specific plugins, enhancements, and wiki pages are available at [vim.org](http://www.vim.org).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. I think I was lazy ^_^ since the day I've switched back to Windows.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I checked out your AcpComplPop at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879
I just want to ask you, what is <your runtime directory> in the installation guide?